# ExactTarget SOAP Request using POSTMAN

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am struggling to perform a SOAP call using POSTMAN. As an example, from the various online technical articles, I am working on retrieving data out of data extension

I gave the header as below -

Host: webservice.s6.exacttarget.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "Retrieve"

The BODY is as below

When I am doing a POST, I get this error "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."

I replaced the UserName, Password and also replaced "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" with "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"

Please advise

```xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>xxxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Test-Man-Filter]</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Cust Id</Properties>
            <Properties>First Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Last Name</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try swapping this line...

```
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx">
```

For this...

```
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
```

Comment: I did that .. but still the same error

Comment: I agree with Macca that it should be "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI".

Comment: This error message is very odd.  Is it possible that your password contains a special character which is throwing off the parsing of the XML?

Comment: I got it work   
Replaced the POST URL from "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl"
TO
"https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx" 

Thank You!